# HTML/CSS Screen overflow issue

Tags: html, css, navigation, width

I am having an issue with my HTML/CSS code that is driving me bunkers.  I'm sure it's something really silly, but I can't seem to find the root cause of this behavior.

For visual reference, I am working on this site http://www.kasiapukeca.com and when you visit the site, everything looks fine.  Now Zoom in to over 100%, say 125-150%+.  My issue is that the canvas area of the top navigation bar does not auto fill to the right when the nav content stretches.  Any ideas?

I have tried width:100% and width:auto and this still doesn't seem to fix it.  The odd thing is when I manually specify a width dimension like width:3000px then the background stretches out.
[image: Here is a screenshot also for reference.]

Answer (score 0):

I see a div just before kp-stack1 that has no class id to it. That div is what is preventing that navigation bar from stretching with it.

You should give that div an id of container and mess with the width on that to get the results you want.

Edit: Actually, I just took a second look. The width of the HTML only goes as far as 900px. You'd want the HTML to cover the whole page, so that the body can go further horizontally as well. If you style the body to go to 1500px, you'll see that the navigation bar will stretch as far as you'd need it to.

For some reason I can't seem to get the HTML to expand across the whole screen, perhaps someone smarter than me can figure it out.

Comment: Yes, there is a container div which I didn't name.  I didn't think to mess with that, but maybe I should give it a shot at this point.

Comment: Well, the biggest problem is the HTML not expanding across horizontally. Once the HTML is adjusted then everything else will follow suit. That div is being cut off by the body, which is being cut off by the HTML element itself. Try what webkit suggested, I couldn't figure out how to change it myself :(

Answer (score 0):

Your 'BODY' is being cut off because in general your page is not responsive.. meaning, if you have elements that their fixed width will be more then the width of the viewport, you'll get a horizontal scroll bar, which you don't want because then your BODY will cut out.. my advice is add these to your css as a starting point.. then tweak to get your wanted end result:

## CSS

```
html, body      { width:100%;}
#kp-stack1      { background-size:contain;}
.stackWrapper   { width:100%;}
#kp-card        { width:50%; min-width:304px; max-width:320px; box-sizing:border-box;}
#kp-pricehome   { width:45%; box-sizing:border-box;}
```

**Notice** though when you zoom, your navigation will get cut.. you need to think how you want to approach this, either reduce font-size to keep the strip inside the viewport.. or some other solution..

Comment: Thanks @webkit I will give that a try.  I was also considering the font-size reduction approach.

Comment: any tips for dynamically checking when/if the fixed width is larger than the viewport?

Comment: Why would you want to check that? if you want to leave in fixed widths for your layouts, you could use css media queries as break points for changing style rules according to screen resolution (size).. say if your layout width is 1024px, then you could use a media query with 'max-width 1024px' to make rules for when the screen is smaller then that.